# Iterate page in xml body when using api request in Python

Tags: python, xml, api, for-loop, request

I want to get all the data from the api, however the maximum pagesize is 1000.
The way I think is to iterate the page and append the data into a empty dictionary.
However, I don't know how can apply for loop into the string.

Below is the python script copied from postman, the last page is 146.

```
    url = "http://example.com/default/svc-open/web-service-v2"

 body="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/Ec/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:callService>
      <paramsJson>
        {
            "shipDateFor": "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
            "shipDateTo": "2021-02-01 00:00:00",
            "pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":1000}
        }
      </paramsJson>
      <userName>user</userName>
      <userPass>123456</userPass>
      <service>getOrders</service>
    </ns1:callService>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=body)
    
    print(response.text)
```

How can I apply for loop to iterate the page number in the body which is a string and append all the data into a empty dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an fstring to insert the page number into the soap request. Here is an example for the section of the request that requires the page number:

```
>>> page = 10
>>> print(f'''"pagination":{{"page":{page},"pageSize":1000}}''')
"pagination":{"page":10,"pageSize":1000}
```

Note that you need to double up the existing `{` and `}` characters and add `{page}` which is where the value of the variable `page` will be inserted.

To use that in a for loop you would make the `body` string an fstring (by using the `f` prefix) and make the change shown above to the appropriate area of the string. Then you would iterate like this:

```
for page in range(1, 147):
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)
```